# Derivation for the length of a parabola.

Tags: integration, geometry, conic-sections

> $$ \int_{x_1} ^{x_2}\sqrt{1+f^{'}(x)^2}dx$$

I would separately determine limits $x_1, x_2 $ as well as $x_3$(vertex) of the parabola

> $y= a x^2+b x+c$

getting length before inserting limits:

> $ \frac{1}{4a}\left[(2ax+b)+\sqrt{1+(2ax+b)^2}+\log\left((2ax+b)+\sqrt{1+(2ax+b)^2}\right)\right] $

Is it so far correct? Much appreciated.

Comment: math mode please

Comment: @Sokonit, please check if the edit is correct.

Comment: "I would appreciate if" in your title is redundant; it is really understanding something that matters. You can express your appreciation by upvoting and accepting answers.

Comment: In your first equation, there is a typo : it should be $f'(x)$ instead of $f(x)$. Obviously, you made the calculations accordingly.

Comment: @Narasimham. What the OP used is correct. The typo was $f(x)$ instead of $f'(x)$ in the first line.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici ok..

Answer (score 1):

By translating the parabola in such a way that the $x$-coordinate of the vertex is zero, it is trivial that we may assume $y=ax^2$, hence we just need to check that:
$$ \int_{0}^{u}\sqrt{1+4a^2 x^2}\,dx = \frac{u}{2}\sqrt{1+4a^2 u^2}+\frac{1}{4a}\operatorname{arcsinh}(2au).$$
It is interesting to notice that the last integral is related with the area of the circle (it is just its hyperbolic counterpart):
$$ \int_{0}^{u}\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx = \frac{u}{2}\sqrt{1-u^2}+\frac{1}{2}\arcsin u.$$
First piece on the RHS given by the area of a triangle, second piece given by the area of a circular sector.

Comment: I belive the second one I would use to create a segment that would drop down, from the y of the parabola at a certain "x", which I would declare, to y=0.